# How to edit django form data before cleaning/validation?

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I edit the value returned by a django form field before it is validated or saved?

For [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute), If I have:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        # the widget returns user.id's (django-select2 ModelSelect2MultipleWidget
        recipient_ids = self.data['recipients']  

        # need to convert IDs to usernames
        usernames = User.objects.filter(id=recipient_ids).values_list(username, flat=True)

        # now I have a list of usernames, I need to put those back into the data to finish cleaning etc:

        self.data['recipients'] = usernames  # error, data isn't mutable...

        return super().clean()
```

How can I modify the form data `self.data['recipients'] = usernames` before it gets sent for cleaning?

Side note on why I need to do this: I am trying to use Django-select2 ModelSelect2MultipleWidget (which returns pks) for the Django-postman recipients field, but recipients in Django postman can't be ids, it has to be username or some other field (I tried setting POSTNAME_NAME_USER_AS='pk' but postman doesn't accept that, so I'm just using the default which is 'username')

Answer (score 0):

But this is exactly what `clean` (or the specific clean_fieldname methods) is for. For `clean`, you should modify `self.cleaned_data`; for `clean_recipients`, you should simply return the modified data.

Comment: Isn't cleaned_data already cleaned though? I need to edit the data before it's cleaned, so cleaned_data is too late.  I tried clean_recipients, but this seems to be called after the super.clean() method, so the form would fail before it got to my more specific clean_recipients method.

Comment: I don't understand your point. If so then do it in `clean_recipients`, as I said. Either way this is a part of cleaning itself.